# Hide code in packages

Tags: apex, package, code

I packaged a visualforce page and its controller but the code is still able to be seen. How can I hide my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a managed package or an unmanaged package?

Comment: I just went to Build - Packages and there is only one option [new] it says packages, nothing more. I don't know if it's unmanaged or managed

Comment: No, what happens is that didn't explain well what I needed. So, before creating those package I had to use testMethod methods, they didn't tell me. And some many things more. Now I understand how this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to release a managed package instead of an unmanaged package. The code in managed packages is not visible.

> Managed packages are typically used by Salesforce partners to distribute and sell applications to customers. These packages must be
>   created from a Developer Edition organization. Using the AppExchange
>   and the License Management Application (LMA), developers can sell and
>   manage user-based licenses to the app. Managed packages are also fully
>   upgradeable. To ensure seamless upgrades, certain destructive changes,
>   like removing objects or fields, can not be performed. Managed
>   packages also offer the following benefits:
>
> - Intellectual property protection for Apex
> - Built-in versioning support for API accessible components
> - The ability to branch and patch a previous version
> - The ability to seamlessly push patch updates to subscribers
> - Unique naming of all components to ensure conflict-free installs

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm)